# Remove HTML (and add new lines) In Google Sheets Cells

Tags: html, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Trying to determine the best method to automatically remove HTML in all cells within a column in Google Sheets.

Example of cell data:

```
<p><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/logo.png" alt="" width="20%" height="20%" /></p><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<p><br />Termékeik megtalálhatók a világ legkülönlegesebb épületeiben (pl. Bayern München stadion), de felhasználási körük kiterjed az egészségügy, mezőgazdaság, hadiipar és más területekre is.<p><br />Leányvállata, a Palram Applications Ltd. ezt a know-how-t és csúcsminőséget használja ki a széles felhasználó rétegeknek szánt, kellemesen felhasználóbarát termékei fejlesztéséhez.<p><br />A polikarbonát üvegházaik, időtálló kerti házaik piacvezető csúcsminőséget képviselnek kategóriájukban. <p><br /><p><span style="font-size: 16px;"><strong>Palram Skylight 180 x 150 szürke kerti ház</strong></span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 16px;"><strong></strong></span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 14px;">Méretei: 153 * 185 * 217 cm</span></p> <p>Belső méretek: 148 * 170 * 208 cm</p> <p>Ajtó méretei: 127 * 171 cm</p> <p>Oldalfal magassága: 173 cm</p> <p>Belső térfogat 5 m3</p> <p>A csomag mérete: 183 * 105 * 11 cm</p> <p><span><strong></strong></span></p> <p><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Gyakorlatilag törhetetlen, UV védelemmel ellátott polikarbonát falai vannak. A hagyományos PE polietilén műanyag házakkal ellentétben nem törékenyek, és ellenállnak az időjárási viszontagságoknak, a hónak és a jégesőnek is. A fém házakkal ellentétben pedig a falai soha nem rozsdásodnak, nem deformálódnak vagy károsodnak.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> A polikarbonát panelek rögzítése az alumínium profilokban egyedi és egyszerű.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Rozsdamentes a konstrukciója, ami erős alumínium profilokból áll.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Egyedi, fényáteresztő polikarbonát tetőszerkezet biztosítja a belső megvilágítást.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Karbantartásmentes és könnyen mosható. Nincs gond a festéssel, a penésszel vagy a rozsdával sem.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> A zárható és könnyen nyitható ajtó alumínium keretben van.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> A padlója rögzíthető, csúszásmentes.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Minden típus választható barna vagy ezüstös-szürke színben.<br /><br /><strong>Könnyű kezelhetőség</strong><br /><br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Könnyű, egységes csomagolásba szállítják.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Ideális az e- kereskedelem útján történő megrendelés esetében is.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Minimális tárolási helyet igényel szétszerelt állapotban.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> 2 személy az áttekinthető útmutató segítségével egyszerűen összeszerelheti.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> A kész ház könnyen áthelyezhető más helyre.<br /><br /><strong>Nagyon hosszú élettartam és tartósság</strong><br /><br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Gyakorlatilag törhetetlen polikarbonát panelekből áll.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Robusztus alumínium a szerkezete, amely soha nem rozsdásodik.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Kiválóan ellenáll az időjárási viszontagságoknak.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> 100 % UV védelemmel ellátott polikarbonát panelekből áll.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Karbantartásmentes.<br /><span><img src="https://website.com/shop_ordered/3767/pic/pipa_zold.bmp" height="19" width="20" /></span> Rögzíthető a talajhoz</p>]
```

The HTML code looks really messy, exactly like the html code above. I would like to add new lines at the end of `</div>, </p>, <br />`.

I'm not sure if using a regex in the cell as a formula or some type of script would be a better approach.

Comment: At the closing tags of divs, paragraphs, and breaks.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, 
 "</div> ?|</p> ?|<br /> ?", CHAR(10))), " ?</?\S+[^<>]*> ?", )))
```

[image: 0]